POSIXct conversion from character variable to datetime that causes year to start with '00xx' rather than '20xx'. How to fix this?
I am importing multiple csv files from one folder and I've noticed that when I do a conversion to convert a character datetime stamp, the year will read as '0024' rather than '2024'. How do I fix it so it reads '2024'? I'm open to other options that as.POSIXct() function if it fixes the issue.
For example, here is the an example of the data, mirroring exactly the formatting when I import the dataframes from csv into RStudio:
have <- as.data.frame(structure(list(row=structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4)),
                                     Device.Timestamp=structure(c("1/28/24 0:01", "1/28/24 0:05", "1/28/24 0:11", "1/28/24 0:14")))))

This is my current conversion code:
want<-have%>%
        mutate(timestamp=base::as.POSIXct(Device.Timestamp, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))

And then I get this output:

Thank you for your input and insights!

Your data is recorded with 2 digits years so use lower case y, format="%m/%d/%y"

This solved it! Thank you so much!

You could also use have |> mutate(timestamp = lubridate::mdy_hms(Device.Timestamp))

Would someone like to post an answer (or find a duplicate)?

This question is similar to: Trying to extract a date from a 5 or 6-digit number. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
